# Apply title under action icon toolbarAndroid React Native

Tags: react-native, android-toolbar

Hi i'm new in react native so i don't now if it is possible.
I want a toolbarAndroid but i want the title of the actions to show under them instead of default next to them. Also even when the title shows next to the icon it will only show up if there is space for it.

My Toolbar

```
<ToolbarAndroid
      style={styles.toolbar}
      logo={logo}
      actions={[
        {
          title: 'Main', icon: mainIcon, show: 'always', showWithText: true
        },
        ...
```

The style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    height: 50
},
...
```

[How it is and how i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JsDN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best solution until now is editing the icons adding each text to each icon